# descent for formally smooth maps

Tags: schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry, smoothness

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a morphism between schemes and $Y'\rightarrow Y$ a fpqc morphism
such that the base change $f'$ of $f$ to $Y'$ is formally smooth, does it imply that $f$ is formally smooth?

Comment: The answer to this MO question seems relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10731/possible-formal-smoothness-mistake-in-ega

Comment: In the infinitesimal lifting property, can we reduce to easier rings, such local henselian or local for example?

Comment: Section 1.7 of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812034 contains the claim that formal smoothness is a local property in the fpqc topology (presumably meaning local on the target), and says that Gabber can explain why.